# Are parquet files splittable when stored in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

- I know that parquet files are splittable if they are stored in block storage. E.g stored on HDFS
- Are they also splittable when stored in object storage such as AWS s3?
- This confuses me because, object storage is supposed to be atomic. You either access the entire file or none of the file. You can't even change meta data on an S3 file without rewriting the entire file. On the other hand, AWS reccomends using splittable file formats in S3 to improve the performance of Athena and other frameworks in the hadoop ecosystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Parquet files are splittable.

S3 supports positioned reads (range requests), which can be used to read only selected portions of the input file (object).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean here, but generally (I think), you have parquet partition on partition keys and save columns into blocks of rows. When I have used in it AWS S3 it has saved like:

```
|-Folder
|--Partition Keys
|---Columns
|----Rows_1-100.snappy.parquet
|----Rows_101-200.snappy.parquet
```

This handles the splitting efficiencies you mention.

Comment: Hi Kaspar, a splittable file is a single file that readers can access in small chunks rather than having to read the entire file. This means for example that many programs could read different chunks of a file and process it in paralell. Parquet files are splittable files. On the other hand files compressed with gzip are not splittable because the entire contents of the file are needed to decompress the file. What you have described above is not related to whether or not the file is splittable. Instead there are just multiple files

Comment: Hey Arran - thanks for the clarification. As you can probably tell, not hugely knowledgable on this. My question would be, given what you've said above, why would you want one single file, rather than distributing it across multiple files? Just curious.

Comment: No worries Kaspar, this article has a few interesting points. Point number 4 gives a good explanation of the importance of file size https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/